# Does /eɪ/ sound make a slight 'y' sound in the word "DAY"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, phonetics, vowels

I am really confused with this sound **/eɪ/**

It seems that it has a **/j/** or '**aaaay**' sound when it is at the end of the word like:

- Day - /deɪ/
- pray - /preɪ/

Also with words like

- Played

Some people (non-natives) mispronounce it like [pleɪ.jd] because they think that 'y' letter is pronounced here

So, does it make this slight /j/ sound?

Comment: TLDR: Yes! 
........ Does this answer your question? [are the pronuncations of 'ei' and 'ej' the same in İPA?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/276740/are-the-pronuncations-of-ei-and-ej-the-same-in-%c4%b0pa)

Comment: Yes, where nearly all dictionaries use /eɪ/, academic linguists use /ej/ because diphthongs are not two complete vowel sounds, but a vowel plus a "glide". Further, if you actually pronounce /eɪ/ it doesn't make the sound in "play" as accurately as /ej/. There might be a historical reason why dictionaries are like this, but it doesn't reflect the language "as she's spoke".